# Is it possible to construct a new record using Lenses?

Tags: haskell, lenses

If I have a record type with lenses, is it possible to construct a new record without using the underlying record accessors?

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens
import Control.Lens.TH

data Foo = Foo { _s :: String
               , _b :: Bool
               } deriving (Show, Eq)

makeLenses ''Foo
```

I *could* make `Foo` an instance of `Data.Default` and then modifiy `def` with lenses, but not all record types will have sensible defaults. Does Control.Lens have its own way to do it?

Comment: You could always use `Foo{}` as default, leaving all fields undefined.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even know you could omit fields there. I just *assumed* it would be a compile error.

Comment: Note that this won't work if `Foo` has strict fields.

Comment: Good point @shachaf, I didn't consider that. So `Default` instance is required for strict fields and therefore probably is the correct way to go in general to avoid fragile code.

Comment: Also note that you run into an issue with type-changing lenses. E.g. for `data Foo a = Foo { _x, _y :: a }`, the lenses `x` and `y` individually can't change the type, since you have to modify the fields `x` and `y` at once.

Comment: (There's a proposed mechanism that could be used to make type-changing lenses that would work there, but I don't think anyone's written code for it so far.)

Comment: So, in conclusion: This is a minefield! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is currently no way to do that. You'll have to use something like `Foo{}` as default or not use lens for record construction. However, there is already an [issue](https://github.com/ekmett/lens/issues/286) in lens covering this.

Comment: Thanks for link to the github ticket. Some interesting discussion there!